# In PHP, how to extract currency, amount and date from a string?

Tags: php, regex

I have this string.

```
11 Apr 2016 $10,000.00 $10.00 11 May 2016
```

I need to parse the date and the currency values in them by and get it out in arrays of date and amount and a currency variable like,

Date array:

```
Array([0] => "11-Apr-2016", [1] => "11-May-2016")
```

Amount array:

```
Array([0] => "10000.00", [1] => "10.00")

$currency = '$';
```

My Approach was to parse the dates and amounts separately and push it to the respective arrays but got stuck at parsing itself.

Conditions: The date can be of any format, separated by - or / and month could be in digits or text too.  Also the currency is also not only in $.  I have an array of all the available currency codes for this. I'm using it by checking the existence of values after exploding the string for finding the currency.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Then you need two separated patterns.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant by parsing the date and amount separately.  I couldn't find a regex for extracting the date which is separated by space. Also, couldn't figure out a way to get the amount out too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string:

```
$str = "11 Apr 2016 $10,000.00 $10.00 11 May 2016";
```

---

Use this pattern to get *"date array:"*

```
preg_match_all("/(\d{1,2} [a-zA-Z]+ \d{4})/", $str, $date_array);
print_r($date_array);
```

#### [Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nY7qS9/2)

---

And use this patterh to get *"amount array:"*

```
preg_match_all("/\\$[^ ]+/", $str, $amount_array);
print_r($amount_array);
```

#### [Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eI3aS7/1)

---

And [here is a PHP Demo](https://3v4l.org/Z6bj5) for both of them.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you.

```
    $phrase  = "1 Apr 2016 $10,000.00 $10.00 11 May 2016";
    $currency = array('$');
    $phrase = explode(' ', $phrase);

    $date_one = $phrase[0] . '-' . $phrase[1] . '-' . $phrase[2];
    $date_two = $phrase[5] . '-' . $phrase[6] . '-' . $phrase[7];

    $price_one = $phrase[3];
    $price_two = $phrase[4];

    $price_one = str_replace($currency, '', $price_one);
    $price_two = str_replace($currency, '', $price_two);
    $date = array($date_one, $date_two);
    $price = array($price_one, $price_two);
```